# Harmonize multiple choice number formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document (word 2010) approx 1000 pages with 2000+ questions which are of the following format:

```
1. This is question text multiple lines
(a) Option 1
(b) Option 2
(c) Option 3
(d) Option 4

2. Next question text mutliple lines
A. Option 1
b) Option 2
c] Option 3
D) Option 4
```

and so on....

As Shown above, the word numbering in front of Options vary from question to question.
I need to all them in the following format:

```
A. Option 1
B. Option 2
C. Option 3
D. Option 4
```

These options need to have left indent at 1cm and hanging 1cm.

I googled around and it looks that I need to use 
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListValue

to get the bullet value
So far i have written (incomplete macro):

```
numOfLines = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("NUMBER OF LINES")

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

For x1 = 1 To numOfLines
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        bulletValue = Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListValue
        If bulletValue = 0 OR bulletValue = 1 OR bulletValue = 2 OR bulletValue=3 Then
        'THis is where i have no clue what to do next

        EndIf
Next x1
```

This counter x1 is also a problem because i need to skip 4 lines containing 4 option and then move ahead. How?

Comment: Have you looked at the idea of converting the document to a text document which would make it easier to pull out all the question with a regular expression or something then rewrite into new document?  Would this be possible?

Comment: @Toby Allen: I am not exactly clear what you mean. But by converting to text, i will loose all the formatting for the document. Isn't is? Reformatting the document may not be option as the document was created by someone else and lot of effort went into it.

Comment: If you still didn't get an answer you can email me your file and i will take a look at it for you

Comment: Are those lists of answers actually bulleted lists, or just hand-typed? If they're real bulleted lists it's odd that the formatting would vary so much.